# How to create a custom filter in Wordpress?

Tags: search

I am creating a e learning site where i want  provide my visitors a functionality to get the results which they need .

Suppose a visitor needs  to find the colleges in a particular location. So I want to filter the results by providing them a  3 drop downs like State , On selecting state it should display the cities and finally select the course and on submitting they get the required result.

I don't have the idea how to do it. Please help me  with your valuable suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Register hierarchical taxonomy for locations/courses. Use jQuery to populate cities depending on the chosen state and courses depending on the chosen city. Use WP_Query with [taxonomy parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) to get the result.

Comment: Can you be more specific or guide me to a tutorial .

Comment: I'm already specific and give you the whole workflow. Also, I can't decide which tutorial of hundreds befits better, so you have to choose it yourself.